# Windows server 2012- setting up client for domain and local account?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

I have a specific windows 8.1 computer that I am wanting to have as part of a windows server 2012 r2 domain but also be able to login to the computer and use it as a local user with full access to its drives and files (like a personal computer not part of a domain)

How would I configure the client to be able to do this?

Also is it possible to share a folder on the server with a computer on the network that is not part of the domain?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

After joining a client to the domain you can still login with a local account.
And yes you can also share folders with non-domain computers. This is all a matter of how access rights are set on the share.

Comment: For bonus points: Think of what would happen if you walked away from the domain and lost your connection (cached credentials not withstanding). You wouldn't be able to log into your own machine for the end of time without local accounts. You'd have to reimage the whole machine.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the local account on a domain-computer you need to use `.\<local username>` insted of `<domin username>` on the login screen

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you can still log into a domain computer with a local account.

In order to access remote shares, you'll have to either

1. Share the shares with "guest" (meh),
2. Use a local account with the same username and password as a domain account that has access to the shares, or
3. Manually or scriptomatically map the shares with domain account credentials.

I recommend 2 or 3.